# How do I more properly utilize useEffect and useFrame to calculate this n-body simulation?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, physics, react-three-fiber

I have been working on a brute force approach for a n-body simulation based on this exercise I stumbled upon:
https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs126/assignments/nbody.html

The code somewhat ""works"" and is available on my github:
https://github.com/jeromejanicot/threejs-fun

## My main questions

Is my use of setInterval inside the useEffect proper?
Where should I perform my calculations?
How do I synchronize my calculation between the useEffect and the useFrame hook?
Is there anything particularly bad with the way I am doing things?

## An overview of how things work:

I have defined the functions used to calculate the pairwise force between two objects, and the directional acceleration for an object:

src/gravitational/nBodySim.ts

```js
export type Coordinate = [x: number, y: number, z: number];
export interface Particle {
  name: string;
  position: Coordinate;
  color: string;
  size: number;
  mass: number;
  velocity: Coordinate;
  netForces: Coordinate;
  acceleration: Coordinate;
}

export function pairwiseForce(
  G: number,
  particle1: Particle,
  particle2: Particle
) {
  const distanceSquared =
    ((particle2.position[0] - particle1.position[0]) ** 2 +
      (particle2.position[1] - particle1.position[1]) ** 2 +
      (particle2.position[2] - particle1.position[2]) ** 2) **
    2;
  const x =
    ((G * (particle1.mass * particle2.mass)) / distanceSquared) *
    (particle2.position[0] - particle1.position[0] / distanceSquared);
  const y =
    ((G * (particle1.mass * particle2.mass)) / distanceSquared) *
    (particle2.position[1] - particle1.position[1] / distanceSquared);
  const z =
    ((G * (particle1.mass * particle2.mass)) / distanceSquared) *
    (particle2.position[2] - particle1.position[2] / distanceSquared);
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    z: z,
  };
}

export function acceleration(netForces: Coordinate, m: number) {
  const ax = netForces[0] / m;
  const ay = netForces[1] / m;
  const az = netForces[2] / m;
  return {
    ax: ax,
    ay: ay,
    az: az,
  };
}
```

I then use these formulas to compute the position of the objects inside of a useEffect.
The shape of the Objects:

```js
const particle1: Particle = {
  name: "particle1",
  position: [0, 0, 12],
  color: "blue",
  mass: 100,
  size: 1,
  velocity: [1, 1, 1],
  netForces: [0, 0, 0],
  acceleration: [0, 0, 0],
};
```

The useEffect with a setInterval. I am sure I am breaking a lot of best practices and I would appreciate feedback on my use of the React api.
Also, I am not quite sure my numerical integration is proper, but that's something I can look up elsewhere.

src/App.tsx

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const positionTracker = setInterval(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        const netForces: Coordinate = [0, 0, 0];

        for (let j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
          if (i == j) {
            continue;
          }
          const { x, y, z } = pairwiseForce(
            gravitationalConstant,
            particles[i],
            particles[j]
          );
          netForces[0] += x;
          netForces[1] += y;
          netForces[2] += z;
        }
        // 1 - Calculate velocity at t+delta/2
        // acceleration t
        const { ax, ay, az } = acceleration(netForces, particles[i].mass);

        // velocity at t - delta/2 (for initial velocity of 1 then 0.5?) initial velocity * 0.25
        const vMinusDeltaX = particles[i].velocity[0] / 2;
        const vMinusDeltaY = particles[i].velocity[1] / 2;
        const vMinusDeltaZ = particles[i].velocity[2] / 2;
        // vfd/2 = vpd/2 * at
        const vPlusDeltaX = vMinusDeltaX + ax;
        const vPlusDeltaY = vMinusDeltaY + ay;
        const vPlusDeltaZ = vMinusDeltaZ + az;

        // 2 - Calculate Position of Particule based on vfd/2
        setParticles(
          produce((draft) => {
            draft[i].netForces = [netForces[0], netForces[1], netForces[2]];
            draft[i].position = [
              particles[i].position[0] + vPlusDeltaX,
              particles[i].position[1] + vPlusDeltaY,
              particles[i].position[2] + vPlusDeltaZ,
            ];
            draft[i].velocity = [
              particles[i].velocity[0] + vPlusDeltaX,
              particles[i].velocity[1] + vPlusDeltaY,
              particles[i].velocity[2] + vPlusDeltaZ,
            ];
          })
        );
      }
      console.log("useEffect");
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(positionTracker);
  });
```

I pass the newly computed position of the objects to `react-three-fiber` components.

```
 return (
    <>
      ...
      <Canvas shadows camera={{ position: [0, 20, 0], far: 10000 }}>
        <ambientLight />
        <directionalLight position={[0, 0, 5]} color={"white"} />
        <Physics gravity={[0, 50, 0]}>
          {particles.map((particle) => (
            <Node key={particle.name} id={particle.name} particle={particle} />
          ))}
        </Physics>
        <OrbitControls makeDefault />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  );
```

And then use the data inside the `useFrame` hook from the `react-three-cannon` library.

src/three/components/node.tsx

```js
interface NodeProps {
  id: string;
  particle: Particle;
}

export default function Node(props: NodeProps) {
  const { id, particle } = props;
  const [ref, api] = useSphere(() => ({
    mass: 1,
    args: [particle.size],
    position: particle.position,
  }));
  useFrame(() => {
    api.position.set(
      particle.position[0],
      particle.position[1],
      particle.position[2]
    );
  });
  return (
    <mesh ref={ref as React.RefObject<Mesh<BufferGeometry>>} key={id}>
      <sphereGeometry />
      <meshStandardMaterial color={particle.color} />
    </mesh>
  );
}
```

I am aware that it is not a good idea to mutate state inside of for loops, but I am failing to see another way around.

I tried to play with `instancedMesh` for the objects, but I failed to see how I could have more control over the specific properties of each object (color, mass, velocity etc).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the immer `produce()` to generate a new state. You make all mutations inside the `produce()` callback by "mutating" the old state (`particles`), and getting a new state, which you then set.

We can extract the entire update function (`updateParticles`), because it's not dependent on outside data. Since you're [currying the producer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/curried-produce/), it returns a function that will be called with the base state. You can do all the loops inside this function. You can now use the function as the [updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-parameters) of `useState`.

```
const updateParticles = produce((particles: Particle[]) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    const netForces: Coordinate = [0, 0, 0];
    for (let j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
      if (i == j) continue;
      const { x, y, z } = pairwiseForce(
        gravitationalConstant,
        particles[i],
        particles[j]
      );
      netForces[0] += x;
      netForces[1] += y;
      netForces[2] += z;
    }
    // 1 - Calculate velocity at t+delta/2
    // acceleration t
    const { ax, ay, az } = acceleration(netForces, particles[i].mass);

    // velocity at t - delta/2 (for initial velocity of 1 then 0.5?) initial velocity * 0.25
    const vMinusDeltaX = particles[i].velocity[0] / 2;
    const vMinusDeltaY = particles[i].velocity[1] / 2;
    const vMinusDeltaZ = particles[i].velocity[2] / 2;
    // vfd/2 = vpd/2 * at
    const vPlusDeltaX = vMinusDeltaX + ax;
    const vPlusDeltaY = vMinusDeltaY + ay;
    const vPlusDeltaZ = vMinusDeltaZ + az;

    // 2 - Calculate Position of Particule based on vfd/2
    particles[i].netForces = [netForces[0], netForces[1], netForces[2]];
    particles[i].position = [
      particles[i].position[0] + vPlusDeltaX,
      particles[i].position[1] + vPlusDeltaY,
      particles[i].position[2] + vPlusDeltaZ,
    ];
    particles[i].velocity = [
      particles[i].velocity[0] + vPlusDeltaX,
      particles[i].velocity[1] + vPlusDeltaY,
      particles[i].velocity[2] + vPlusDeltaZ,
    ];
  }
});
```

Your `useEffect` doesn't have a dependency array currently, which means that it's executed on every render (when `particles` are updated). This means that the cleanup function is called, and a new interval is created. You're actually using `setInterval` as `setState`.

Since the state update is not dependent on the `particles` state, because it's passed to the `updatedPrticles` from `setParticles`, you can set an empty dependency array (`[]`) to `useEffect`, and the interval would only be cleared when the component unmounts:

```
export function App() {
  const [particles, setParticles] = useState<Particle[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const positionTracker = setInterval(() => {
      setParticles(updateParticles); // use the updater function
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(positionTracker);
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

An alternative is to use `setTimeout`, and let the change in `particles` triggers the `useEffect`, and starts a new step:

```
export function App() {
  const [particles, setParticles] = useState<Particle[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const positionTracker = setTimeout(() => {
      setParticles(updateParticles(particles)); // create new state and update
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(positionTracker);
  }, [particles]);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

I'm not familiar enough with React Three Fiber, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I learned some good practices and good tips.
I am encountering an issue with the setInterval in the useEffect tho: despite me trying to catch the current value of `particles` it is still using a stale one.
```jsx
const positionTracker = setInterval(() => {
      setParticles((particles) => updateParticles(particles));
    }, 1000);
```
I have updated the `updateParticles` appropriately 
```jsx
 const updateParticles = <T extends Particle[]>(prevState: T) =>
    produce(prevState, (draft) => {...}
```
It works perfectly for two other repro I set up.

Comment: The updated `particles` is passed by `setParticles`, add a `console.log(particles)` to the body of the component (not inside `useEffect`), and see if it actually changes. Calling `setParticles(updateParticles)` is enough, because it's a function that accepts a `particles` state. No need to wrap it in an arrow function.

Comment: Also see 2nd option by using `setTimeout()`.

Comment: For me it seems to be stuck with stale data from the first useEffect run. Like my specific project refuses to update correctly,  my other test repos work with the pattern you presented.